# maximum cumulative decision limit

Tags: hypothesis-testing, sequential-analysis

It is well-known that it is problematic to stop an A/B test before we obtain a required number of samples. This website "[A/B Testing Rigorously (without losing your job)](http://elem.com/~btilly/ab-testing-multiple-looks/part1-rigorous.html)" explains how to stop safely an A/B test in the middle of the test.

At the website we define **maximum cumulative decision limit** by

$$\frac{pn}{n+10000}.$$

Here $p$ is the significance level and $n$ is the number of "conversion".

My question is: where does the formula come from?